# WKWebKit Mac OS NSPrintOperation

Tags: objective-c, macos, wkwebview, nsprintoperation

WebKit 1 exposed the WebFrameView where I could call a print operation.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender printFrameView:(WebFrameView *)frameView {
  NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [frameView printOperationWithPrintInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo]];
  [printOperation runOperation];
}
```

With WKWebKit API I can't seem to figure out how to perform a similar action or which view to grab for printing. All my efforts have come up with blank pages.

Comment: see [How does one Print a WKWebView on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319295/how-does-one-print-a-wkwebview-on-osx) and http://www.openradar.me/23649229

Answer (score 12):

**macOS 11 update**: the [printOperation(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3516861-printoperation) method is no longer private and is now the solution that I use in my apps.

Amazingly, `WKWebView` still doesn't support printing on macOS, despite the legacy WebView being deprecated.

Looking at https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/0dfc67a174b79a8a401cf6f60c02150ba27334e5 , printing was implemented years ago as a private API, but for some reason, has not been exposed. If you don't mind using a private API, you can print a `WKWebView` with:

```swift
public extension WKWebView {
    // standard printing doesn't work for WKWebView; see http://www.openradar.me/23649229 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151276
    @available(OSX, deprecated: 10.16, message: "WKWebView printing will hopefully get fixed someday – maybe in 10.16?")
    private static let webViewPrintSelector = Selector(("_printOperationWithPrintInfo:")) // https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/0dfc67a174b79a8a401cf6f60c02150ba27334e5


    func webViewPrintOperation(withSettings printSettings: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey : Any]) -> NSPrintOperation? {
        guard self.responds(to: Self.webViewPrintSelector) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let po: NSPrintOperation = self.perform(Self.webViewPrintSelector, with: NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printSettings))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSPrintOperation else {
            return nil
        }

        // without initializing the print view's frame we get the breakpoint at AppKitBreakInDebugger:
        // ERROR: The NSPrintOperation view's frame was not initialized properly before knowsPageRange: returned. This will fail in a future release! (WKPrintingView)
        po.view?.frame = self.bounds

        return po
    }
}
```

You can have this be the default print operation for your `NSDocument` subclass by adding:

```swift
    override func printOperation(withSettings printSettings: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey : Any]) throws -> NSPrintOperation {
        return myWebView.webViewPrintOperation(withSettings: printSettings) ?? try super.printOperation(withSettings: printSettings)
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without private API?

Comment: Don't really see how this works. When I try it in my App targeting 10.14 running on 10.15. I crash with the following error: ERROR: The NSPrintOperation view's frame was not initialized properly before knowsPageRange: returned. This will fail in a future release! (WKPrintingView)

Comment: That message comes from a `AppKitBreakInDebugger` breakpoint – it isn't actually a crash, since you can just resume the debugger. However, I've updated the sample code with the workaround, which is to manually set the print operation's view's frame.

Comment: Yeah, I've been struggling with this for several days.  I have the method working fine (sorta) in WebVew but need to try to get it working in WKWebView.  Unfortunately, calling the printOp directly functions as expected (generates an empty document) but I can't for the life figure out how to get your code plugged in to test it.  I tried just putting the extension in place and it wasn't getting called.  Tried calling your function directly but it doesn't even generate an empty file (ie, no print at all) I don't have an NSDocument to override as I'm in a ViewBased app

Comment: So, uh, will using this private API get the app rejected in review?

Comment: @Tritonal It's public now. Also, I found that I needed to call `runOperationModalForWindow` on the `NSPrintOperation` instance, probably because the reference I am using is local to the method that does the printing. Otherwise, the page ends up blank and the job is stuck in the queue

Answer (score 2):

Here is marcprux swift solution in Objective C:

```
    SEL printSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_printOperationWithPrintInfo:");
    if ([self.webView respondsToSelector:printSelector]) {
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
          NSPrintOperation *printOperation = (NSPrintOperation*) [self.webView performSelector:printSelector withObject:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo]];
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop

        return printOperation;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting on **macOS 11** this is not private anymore: [printOperation(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3516861-printoperation)

Usage:

```swift
let info = NSPrintInfo.shared
    
// configure info...

let operation = webView.printOperation(with: info)
```