# MacOS PDF/Printing from WKWebView is poor quality

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf, wkwebview, nsprintoperation

I've been using what seems to be a standard way of generating prints/PDF's on MacOS by using a `WebView` to generate the contents and the following to print/save as a PDF.

```
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:[[[sender mainFrame] frameView] documentView]
                                                                      printInfo:self.printInfo];
```

This works great, however `WebView` has been deprecated since 10.14 and with 10.15 on the way it's time to move over to `WKWebView`.
Passing the `WKWebView`'s view to the `NSPrintOperation` always gives a blank page which has been reported in several other questions here.

I have it all working with the following code:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:printRect configuration:configuration];
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.13))
{   
    if (@available(macOS 10.13, *))
    {
        [webView takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:nil completionHandler:^(NSImage *snapshotImage, NSError *error) {

            if (!error)
            {   
                NSRect vFrame = NSZeroRect;
                vFrame.size = [snapshotImage size];
                NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:vFrame];
                [imageView setImage:snapshotImage];

                NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:imageView
                                                                                  printInfo:self.printInfo];

                if (self.saveToFilename)
                {
                    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = NO;
                    printOperation.showsProgressPanel = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = YES;
                    printOperation.showsProgressPanel = YES;
                }

                BOOL success = [printOperation runOperation];

                if (self.printCompletionBlock) self.printCompletionBlock(success);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

It generates an image snapshot of the `WKWebView` then uses an `NSImageView` to pass to the `NSPrintOperation`.
The problem is that the quality of the PDF/Print is not as good as the old method.

[image: OLD]
[image: NEW]

How can I get the same quality from a WKWebView that I did from the old WebView?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for printing on macOS from a WKWebView.

See:

[How does one Print all WKWebView On AND Offscreen content OSX and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319295/how-does-one-print-all-wkwebview-on-and-offscreen-content-osx-and-ios)

Comment: What would be an alternative to using a WKWebView? So many apps generate prints, so what other way than using a html?

Comment: You could include wkhtmltopdf (https://wkhtmltopdf.org) in your application, when you need to produce a PDF.

Comment: @Darren printing an offscreen view is a possible way. It depends on the data and the print.

Comment: @AntoineRosset `wkhtmltopdf` looks great, but I can't find any info anywhere on how I might add this to an app to work independently of pre-installing it. Any tips?